# CUDA: using structures and classes inside device kernel

Tags: c++, class, cuda

is there a way to use inside *global* kernel:

1) Simple structures like:

```
Structure Pixel{
    float p;
 }
```

2) Classes with functions and overloaded operators (C++)

3) std:: vector?

Thanks

Comment: So classes with vector structures inside are not allowed? sad((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. No

In general, C++ support is spelled out in [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support):

> For the host code, nvcc supports whatever part of the C++ ISO/IEC 14882:2003 specification the host c++ compiler supports.
>
> For the device code, nvcc supports the features illustrated in Code Samples with some restrictions described in Restrictions; it does not support run time type information (RTTI), exception handling, and the C++ Standard Library.

There are many [CUDA sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#basic-keyconcepts) that demonstrate various C++ support/features, including [overloading](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cppoverload).

[Thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) is a template library that allows usage of (thrust) vector containers with various forms of parallelization (including GPU acceleration).  Users of STL vector containers and algorithms will find thrust constructs familiar.  The [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) may be of interest.